# DynamicReports/JasperReports third party unicode Font issue

Tags: java, pdf, printing, jasper-reports, dynamic-reports

I am using DynamicReports and struggling with getting the corrent printout, when i call .show() everything is perfect, but when i print it, either to an image using image printer or to PDF using Foxit Printer or even to my LaserJet Printer, result is same as shown in the picture below.
**I have tried making .jar using this link [here](http://jasperstarter.sourceforge.net/unicode-pdf-export.html)**

And i checked my PDF it has embedded font whihc i am using "Nafees Noori Nastaleeq" and their is certainly no issue in the font but the issue that my charaters are being distorted i dont know why...
...

Any help will be appreciated, i got not much time limit to do this.
...
[img]http://s17.postimg.org/j7lywrpr3/report_issue.png[/img]

UPDATE:
I tried exporting to PDF directly from the program and in that PDF i cannot see any unicode characters, i also installed iReport to check the issue and this issue was same(no unicode in directly exported PDF and missing and distorted unicode characters in printing form any pdf printer or physical printer.) So i suspect the issue is not with my DynamicReport configuration its with Font or some genric settings which are not working.

Comment: I confirmed the issue is with font, if i use windows default font, no issue occurs.
Issue occurs with custom font

Comment: I used default and thoma fonts which gave perfect results the issue comes with any other of about 60+ urdu fonts i have installed on my computer.
I tried many of them but no luck.
BTW i am using http://jameel-noori-nastaleeq-urdu-fonts.software.informer.com/2.1/ this font, it is nice and clear and good readable.

Comment: share your code please

Comment: Its a whole project and i am facing same issue in just a simple report with unicode characters form my database.
And check my own answer below, issue was in font not being supported or something.
Thankyou for your interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, no answer so better answer my own question.
The issue was that this font i am using and many other fonts (about 80% of my collection of urdu fonts) are behaving same.
Where some other fonts are working good, i have created a list of fonts which worked for me.
Pasting it here so that others may get some help if they need.
Urdu Nastaliq Unicode
Al_Qalam Tehreeri

****LIST****

Arial
Arial Unicode MS

Attari_Sulus
Attari_Abbas

Microsoft Sans Serif
Microsoft Uighur//issue bit

Nafees Web Naskh

UL Sajid Heading//issues in date
Urdu Najd v3//same issue

//downloaded and installed for chekcing
Adobe Arabic
AlFars 7 Kodak Bold//
AlFars 18 Aban
AlFars 6 Kamran Bold

AlQalam Nabeel

Dubai Unicode
Zohar Unicode

AA Sameer Zikran
AA Sameer Armaa Unicode

......................

This is a great repository of urdu fonts if anyone need this.
http://font.urduweb.org/
...
Lastly i would like to know how can i check any font file for such corruptions and if the font is 100% ok and will work in all scenarios, is there a generic way to check all fonts against any language?